# Generate a visual representation of a graph (graph theory)

Tags: visualization, graphviz

Given the following paths on a directed graph:

```
(A --> B --> C)

(C --> B)

(C --> A)
```

I want to find a way to generate a visual representation for this directed graph. Is there any  available software that is capable of doing this?

Comment: Here's an example of the type of image that I'd like to generate: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:4-tournament.svg&page=1

Comment: Perhaps this question should be migrated to mathematica.stackoverflow.com - it might be possible to do this in Mathematica.

Comment: On Stackoverflow, I found a Javascript library for this purpose: http://www.graphdracula.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use dot of the [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) suite. Here's [a simple example of the language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language).

```
digraph graphname {
     a -> b -> c;
     b -> d;
 }
```

[image: example]

Comment: Is GraphViz available for Linux?

Comment: @AndersonGreen Yup, go to the download page for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do graphs like this using an Excel Scatter (XY) chart.  Generally, the best way would be to:

1. Create an XY point for each node.
2. Create a series for each path.
3. Format the series with end points to indicate which direction the path represents.
4. Format everything else, so it doesn't look like an Excel chart.

The result could look something like this:

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0):

The [R language](https://www.r-project.org) is ideal for this, especially with large/changing datasets. Here's a [simple guide](http://www.shizukalab.com/toolkits/sna/plotting-directed-networks).

You'll need an R development enviroment, I use [revolution analytic's](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/revolution-r-open).